# LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL not working in django2.1

Tags: django

I am learning Django and i am having hard time integrating built-in Django login systems. In `settings.py` I have provided `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`. `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` is working fine when I click Logout button. Button `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is not working when I have provided with login credentials.

```
settings.py
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'post_list'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'post_list'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog',   
]

urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
path(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]

blog/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import (BlogListView, BlogDetailView, BlogCreateView, BlogUpdateView, BlogDeleteView)

urlpatterns = [
path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
path('post/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', BlogDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
]
login.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>
<form action="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{{form.as_p}}

<button type='submit'>Login</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}

base.html
<body>

<div class="container">
    <header>
        <div class="nav-left">
            <h1><a href="/">Django Blog</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class=nav-right>
            <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}"> + New Blog Post. </a>
        </div>
    </header>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Hi! {{user.username}}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
    {% else %}
        <p>You are not logged in. </p>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in settings.py file as

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/app/post_list/'
```

Add this to your login urls to urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html', 'redirect_field_name': '/app/post_list'}),
```

Comment: The current path, accounts/login/post, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in blog_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='post_list']
post/<int:pk>/ [name='post_detail']
post/new/ [name='post_new']
post/<int:pk>/edit/ [name='post_edit']
post/<int:pk>/delete/ [name='post_delete']
accounts/ login/ [name='login']
accounts/ logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/ password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/ password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/ password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/ password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']

Comment: accounts/ reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/ reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
The current path, accounts/login/post, didn't match any of these.

Comment: This is displayed on the error page that it searched for all the urls and didn't find one i.e., The current path, accounts/login/post didn't match any of these.